# Send array through intent?

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, parcelable

I am trying to send an array of StatusBarNotifications to another service of mine so I have tried this:

Service that extends `NotificationListenerService`:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StatusBarNotification[] activeN = super.getActiveNotifications();               

    Intent i = new Intent("com.project.now.CORETWO");
    i.putExtra("activenotfications", activeN);
    startService(i);
}
```

Service to receive array through intent:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("abc", "onStartCommand"); 
    activeNotifications = (StatusBarNotification[]) intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("activenotifications"); //This line throws exception
}
```

**Edit**

However I get a `ClassCastException`(marked above with comment)

Here is the log:

```
08-22 22:49:22.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 22:49:22.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20801): Process: com.project.now, PID: 20801
08-22 22:49:22.319: E/AndroidRuntime(20801): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.project.now.CoreTwo@425ed8d0 with Intent { act=com.project.now.CORETWO (has extras) }: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification[]
```

I read quite a bit about sending objects through intents and about `implementing Parcelable`, although it was pretty complicated, see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.java) for example. But from what I can see StatusBarNotification (see API doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html)) already implements Parcelable, thus I should be able to send it through an intent with all of its content, right?

Would really appreciate some help here as I am stuck, thanks

Comment: Same principle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error

Comment: @BrodoFraggins thanks for the link, that did it for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead

```
activeNotifications = (StatusBarNotification[]) intent.getExtras().get("activenotifications");
```

call

```
Parcelable[] parcelable = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("activenotifications");
StatusBarNotification[] sbn = Arrays.copy(parcelable, parcelable.lenght, StatusBarNotification[].class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get a NullPointerException at the same point. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: I realized that I had spelt the tag incorrectly (they didn't match), that was a stupid mistake. However, I still get an Exception (ClassCastException) when I try to receive the intent (see my code). Would appreciate it if you could look at it again, thanks again

Comment: I was rushing a bit with my answer. Of course this casting would not work. You already got it right from others but I have updated my answer to be complete and useful for other SO visitors.

Answer (score 1):

For the `ClassCastException`, see: [I don't get why this ClassCastException occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745893/i-dont-get-why-this-classcastexception-occurs)

Basically you take the Parcelable array, iterate over it, and copy the items into a StatusBarNotification array by casting the items while iterating.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, I used the Arrays.copyOf() method which seems to do the whole process for me (suggested by Brodo Fraggins)