# RuntimeException when trying to getParcelableArray in target activity

Tags: android, bundle, parcelable, runtimeexception

I'm trying to pass an array of custom objects to an activity.  I've implemented parcelable as such:

```
public class WidgetState {

    static class Light implements Parcelable
    {
        int id;
        String text;
        int offColor,onColor;
        boolean on=false;

        boolean isRows;
        int size;

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Light> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Light>() {
        public Light createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Light(in);
        }

        public Light[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Light[size];
        }
    };
        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public Light(Parcel src)
        {
            id = src.readInt();
            text = src.readString();
            offColor = src.readInt();
            onColor = src.readInt();
            on = src.readInt()==1;
            isRows = src.readInt()==1;
            size = src.readInt();
        }

        public Light() { }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeInt(id);
            dest.writeString(text);
            dest.writeInt(offColor);
            dest.writeInt(onColor);
            dest.writeInt(on?1:0);
            dest.writeInt(isRows?1:0);
            dest.writeInt(size);            
        }       
    }
}
```

I can put a single object in the bundle in the launching activity and retrieve it via

```
bundle.putParcelable(new WidgetState.Light(),"light");
```

and retrieve it in the resulting activity via

```
WidgetState.Light light = (WidgetState.Light)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("light")
```

but when packing and array like this

```
bundle.putParcelableArray(new WidgetState.Light[4],"lights");
```

I can do this just fine on the first activity

```
WidgetState.Light[] lights = (WidgetState.Light[])bundle.getParcelableArray("lights");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

but in the second activity i get a RuntimeException when I call

```
WidgetState.Light [] lights = (WidgetState.Light []) state.getParcelableArray("lights");
```

Here's all the code in the first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GuiActivity.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("light", new WidgetState.Light());
bundle.putParcelableArray("lights", new WidgetState.Light[4]);                  

WidgetState.Light[]lights = (WidgetState.Light[])bundle.getParcelableArray("lights");

intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

And the second

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gui);      

    Bundle state = (savedInstanceState!=null)?savedInstanceState:getIntent().getExtras();

    try {
        WidgetState.Light light = (WidgetState.Light) state.getParcelable("light");
        // Throws RuntimeException on next line
        WidgetState.Light [] lights = (WidgetState.Light []) state.getParcelableArray("lights");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Good bundle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    catch ( RuntimeException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to read bundle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Post the LogCat errors too, also it might help to use `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block.

Comment: what was the problem ?

Comment: You can find the solution here: [How to pass an array of Address objects to an other Acitvity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3647432/842697)